# Error in if (s2 < 0) s2 <- 0 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm attempting to generate a simple plot similar to this one
[Bar Graph (gamma)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sDWw.png)
However I'm running into the error:

```
"Error in if (s2 < 0) s2 <- 0 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

followed by:

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
2: In max(dist, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

my code is based of a dataset which has not previously given me any problems until now. Here it is:

```
data_distance_GL <- data_plasto %>% 
  filter(method == "Line Transect",
         species == "GL") %>%  
  select(observer, method, species, distance)
```

```
detectability_GL <- dfuncEstim(distance ~ 1,
                               detectionData = data_distance_GL,
                               likelihood = "Gamma")

plot(detectability_GL)
```

The problem comes with the second chunk of code. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data frame in order to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to write?

```r
if_else(s2 < 0, 0, s2)
```